# Filter a multidimensional array and retain entries which contain a specified substring in any column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, substring, filtering

I want to search for a substring in all columns of a multidimensional array and keep all qualifying data sets.

```
[
    [
        'ConsumerDetail' => [
            'quote_id' => 'QU-12-14-T2887',
            'client_name' => 'asdf asdf',
            'agent_name' => 'flip flob 2313123',
            'zipcode' => 66002,
            'dob' => '01/02/1996',
        ],
    ],
    [
        'ConsumerDetail' => [
            'quote_id' => 'QU-12-14-R4118',
            'client_name' => 'james anderson',
            'agent_name' => 'JOSEPH NEPTUNE',
            'zipcode' => 64656,
            'dob' => '07/16/1958',
        ],
    ],
    [
        'ConsumerDetail' => [
            'quote_id' => 'QU-12-14-W2042',
            'client_name' => 'flip leathers',
            'agent_name' => 'test agen',
            'zipcode' => 65018,
            'dob' => '12/17/1979',
        ],
    ],
]
```

If I search for `flip`, I should get an array with same structure containing `0` and `2` index elements of array. `0` index because it is found in the `agent_name` column and `2` because it is found in `client_name` column.

Desired output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ConsumerDetail' => 
    array (
      'quote_id' => 'QU-12-14-T2887',
      'client_name' => 'asdf asdf',
      'agent_name' => 'flip flob 2313123',
      'zipcode' => 66002,
      'dob' => '01/02/1996',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ConsumerDetail' => 
    array (
      'quote_id' => 'QU-12-14-W2042',
      'client_name' => 'flip leathers',
      'agent_name' => 'test agen',
      'zipcode' => 65018,
      'dob' => '12/17/1979',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: preg_grep() but may be i didnt apply it correct and array_search() but it return only key , i need multiple result and pattern matching

Comment: I found a way may be its not so efficient but it works

`$filteredquotes="";
foreach($my_quotes as $qt):
if(preg_grep("/".$_POST['search']['value']."/",$qt['ConsumerDetail']))
{
    $filteredquotes[]=$qt;
        
}
endforeach;
$my_quotes=$filteredquotes;`

Answer (score 0):

If you flatten the subarrays into a string using a delimiter that won't exist/matter to the comparison, then you can make a simple `strpos()` or `stripos()` check.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TMO1q))

```
$needle = 'flip';
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn($row) => stripos(implode('_', $row['ConsumerDetail']), $needle) !== false
    )
);
```